# ffmpeg extract subclips from video at 10s; 30%; 60%; last 30s of a video

Tags: bash, video, ffmpeg, mp4

I am writing Bash command on a Mac Terminal. To be able to use a loop, I'd like to extract 4 subclips of different inputfile .mp4 videos: 1st subclip (from second 10 to 20), 2nd subclip (10 seconds starting at a 33% stage of the inputfile), 3rd subclip (10 seconds starting at a 66% of the inputfile), and a 4th subclip (10 seconds starting 30seconds before the end of the inputfile).

So far I only know how to make it work with fixed timings (i.e. seconds) but these correspond only to my first video (I have +200):

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$file" -vf "select='between(t, 10, 20) + between(t, 197, 207) + between(t, 393, 403) + between(t, 570,580)',
setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB" -qscale 0 -af "aselect='between(t, 10, 20) + 
between(t, 197, 207) + between(t, 393, 403) + between(t, 570, 580)', 
asetpts=N/SR/TB" ${file%.mp4}_1.mp4; done
```

For the first subclip, I always want from second 10 to 20, so I can leave it as it is, but for the 2nd to 4th subclip I need some formulas, but no idea which ones. Any suggestions?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to get the video duration in seconds:

```
DURATION=$(ffmpeg -i $file 2>&1 | grep "Duration" | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/\..*//g' | awk '{split($1, a, ":"); print 3600*a[1] + 60*a[2] + a[3]}')
```

In this command, you query ffmpeg for the video duration and parse the result by searching for the "Duration" keyword (grep), getting the time field (awk), discard the centiseconds (sed) and parse the H:M:S string into a number of seconds (awk).

Then, you can compute the intervals you need:

```
START1=10
END1=20
START2=$(($DURATION*33/100))
END2=$(($START2+10))
START3=$(($DURATION*66/100))
END3=$(($START3+10))
START4=$(($DURATION-30))
END4=$(($START4+10))
```

You need full seconds, so using the bash approach that returns integers is a good way to go.

You should make sure your video lasts, at least, 30 seconds.

Now, you can start your command with the proper time substitutions:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.mp4
do
    DURATION=$(ffmpeg -i $file 2>&1 | grep "Duration" | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/\..*//g' | awk '{split($1, a, ":"); print 3600*a[1] + 60*a[2] + a[3]}')

    START1=10
    END1=20
    START2=$(($DURATION*33/100))
    END2=$(($START2+10))
    START3=$(($DURATION*66/100))
    END3=$(($START3+10))
    START4=$(($DURATION-30))
    END4=$(($START4+10))

    ffmpeg -i "$file" -vf "select='between(t, $START1, $END1) + between(t, $START2, $END2) + between(t, $START3, $END3) + between(t, $START4, $END4)', setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB" -qscale 0 -af "aselect='between(t, $START1, $END1) +  between(t, $START2, $END2) + between(t, $START3, $END3) + between(t, $START4, $END4)', asetpts=N/SR/TB" ${file%.mp4}_1.mp4
done
```

Comment: That is absolutely awesome! It worked! Just a clarification point, what is the 'ffmpeg -i $file 2>&1' doing? I understand all the remaining code in this first "duration" line just capture information from the first bit of code, right?

Comment: ffmpeg -i $file is getting the file information. The command reads the input file, dumps some interesting information on the standard error and fails because there is no output file defined. But the information we are looking for is already printed in the standard error. Then we use the 2>&1 to redirect the file handler 2 (stderr) to the file handler 1 (stdout). Now it can go thru a standard pipe for further processing and extraction of the duration.

Comment: To see exactly what has been happening, try to execute that line step by step. Start with the first command alone and see what happens. Then add the first pipe and the second command, and check the results... continue till the end.

Comment: Just awesome. Saved me so much time! Thanks again